# How to Show Name Instead of Id in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations

This problem has me completely stumped.  I'm still new at RoR and learning.

I have two tables: Countertops and Countmaterial.  A user will select all the features for their countertop including the material type.  The options for the material are listed in the Countmaterial table and are selection from a collection.

My question is once the selection is made and the Countertop created how do I display the name of the material type on the index page for Countertops instead of the countertype, which is an integer generated to match the name in the Countmaterial table?

I'd rather the index display "Granite" instead of "1", for example.  "Granite" is listed in the Countmaterial table and when the user selects "Granite", it populates the Countertop table as "1" in the countertype column.  Marble is a "2" and so on...

Here's my schema:

```
create_table "countertops", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "size"
 t.string   "color"
 t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
 t.string   "ZipCode"
 t.string   "countertype"
end

create_table "countmaterials", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
 t.integer  "countertop_id"
end
```

My Countertop Controller for index:

```
def index
 @countertops = Countertop.all
 @countertops = Countertop.includes(:countmaterial).all
end
```

My index code:

```
<% @countertops.each do |countertop| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= countertop.ZipCode %></td>
    <td><%= countertop.countmaterial.name %></td>
```

Associations:

```
class Countertop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :countmaterial
end

class Countmaterial < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :countertop
end
```

What do you folks think??

Comment: Isn't `<td><%= countertop.countmaterial.name %></td>` giving you the name?

Comment: Nope.  I get "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" as an error.

Comment: ok lets do some quick debugging.
Please change your index to

<% @countertops.each do |countertop| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= countertop.inspect.to_s %></td>
    <td><%= countertop.countmaterial..inspect.to_s%></td>



It should give out some weird blobs of data, please post those.

Comment: Actually, try this

<% @countertops.each do |countertop| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= countertop.ZipCode %></td>
    <td><%= countertop.countmaterial.name if countertop.countmaterial != nil%></td>

I think you may have some countertop entities without countmaterials in your database

Comment: The error is "bad value for range" for the inspect.to line

Comment: So that second suggestion returned the index page with no values for the countertop material.  If I used countertop.countertype it will return an integer equal to 10.  Weird.

Comment: I have one countertop entity listed in the Countertop table and it has an assigned value of "10" to the countertype variabe.   "10" corresponds to "Marble" in the Countmaterial table, since it was the 10th item created.  "9" is granted and 1-8 were deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to get confused with your specific model names; when naming models and controllers - keep it SUPER simple. One word...

```
#app/models/counter.rb
class Counter < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | type_id | material_id | size_id | color_id | zip_code| created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :type
   belongs_to :material
   belongs_to :size
   belongs_to :color
   delegate :name, to: :size, prefix: true
end

#app/models/option.rb
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | Type | name | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :counters
end

#app/models/size.rb
class Size < Option
end

#app/models/type.rb
class Type < Option
end

#app/models/color.rb
class Color < Option
end

#app/models/material.rb
class Material / Option
end
```

This will give you the ability to do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :counters

#app/controllers/counters_controller.rb
class CountersController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @counters = Counter.all
   end
end

#app/views/counters/index.html.erb
<% @counters.each do |counter| %>
   <%= counter.size_name %>
<% end %>
```

---

To give you context on how this works, you need to know that Rails & Ruby are *object orientated*. This might not mean a lot, but it's vitally important when developing apps with them.

[Object orientated programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is a pattern which puts the *object* at the center of the code. When you understand how this works, nothing will *ever* be the same...

[image]

In "traditional" programming, you work with user flow. This is known as [*event driven* programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming), and although works well for standard apps, it does not suit a Ruby/Rails environment.

Web apps have the capacity to handle so much more data / functionality that it makes perfect sense to treat everything as an object.

Thus, whenever you deal with Ruby, you have to think about *everything* from the perspective of the objects you're trying to [`CRUD` (Create Read Update Destroy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

This is why your `CounterTop` model is a little sketchy - what's the *object* you're trying to invoke?

Once you see that the *object* sits at the core of how Rails works, you'll be able to construct everything around it, as above.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that, Rich.  Although, after reading it, I'm majorly confused.

In this app, I'm trying to make the Countertop the central object around which the app functions.  Thus, the material, the size, the material type, etc, all describe the core Countertop.

I've added Countertype and CountMaterial because I want to eventually expand the app to include other products that would have similar attributes.  So naming a model "color" isn't a smart idea if I have five different products with their own possible colors.

Comment: Also, you have the Counters as belongs_to the attributes instead of the other way around and you have Type in Options and then Type in its own model??  Seems considerably less straightforward then having countercolors, cabinetcolors, countercolors, countermaterial, etc.